# How to copy paste from Ms word to TextView with keeping same format essentially color and bold

Tags: java, android, html

I have  an Ms Word text (about 30 pages) with titles and heading in color and bold and I need to copy paste in 5 parts (activities) as TextView, I usually used the following code: (text1 is string variable, t1 is textview)

```
text1 = "<font color=#000080><b>"
                + "Internal Audit"
                + "</b></font>"
    +<br><font color=#000080><b>Definition of Internal Audit</b></font></br>";
```

`+"<br>Internal auditing is an independent, objective assurance  and consulting activity designed to add value and improve an organization\'s operations. It helps an organization accomplish its objectives by bringing a systematic, disciplined approach to evaluate and improve the effectiveness of risk management, control, and governance processes.</br>"
+"<br></br>";`

```
   t1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text1));
```

;
but now in this case I have a lot of text to format in simplified html, my question is : Is there a better and quick method to copy past a word text with colour and bold to textview, what I need is only to keep the same color and bold no need for same font or other format.
Please help!

Comment: Is this is a 1 time situation?

Comment: I usually format manually the text to cope with the Textview but i consume a lot of boring time, what I'm looking for is if any one has better solution, to apply for this and future cases.